# How to get HTML code form an URL after javascript is loaded

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, url

I'm making an app that gets data from a website.
The website doesn't provide an API so I tried to make it myself.

So here is the problem:
I'm using the following code to pull HTML from a URL:

```
//Get the html code from the URL
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String input;
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuffer.append(input);
}
in.close();
String htmlData = stringBuffer.toString();
```

Now this gives me the loading page of the site. I understand that javascript loads the rest of the site, so my question is: How can I get the HTML from an url after javascript has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some web scraping libraries.Based upon your programming language,there are different libraries for web scraping,below is one of them

https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Comment: Cheerio isn't even written in Java. It's a JavaScript library.

Answer (score 0):

Goof afternoon, if you still try to do it by yourself, instead to use any library as Cheerio, you should make a request before to retrieve the HTML data.

```
public static String getURLSource(String url) throws IOException
{
    URL urlObject = new URL(url);
    URLConnection urlConnection = urlObject.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");

    return toString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
}

private static String toString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
{
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")))
    {
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use some web scraping libraries like cheerio and more. Here I am attaching the tutorial for the same. 
https://codeburst.io/an-introduction-to-web-scraping-with-node-js-1045b55c63f7

Comment: Cheerio isn't even written in Java. It's a JavaScript library.